# If enter more than 10000 in Oracle database it shows in table value as (####) - why?

Tags: oracle11g

I enter more than 10000 in column value in an Oracle database it shows the value like this (#####) symbols, how to solve this problem?

Comment: Try to stretch that cell, the value may be hidden because of length.

Comment: Thanks it's working.